# WCF Service dependencies

Tags: c#, wcf, soa

I have three wcf services A,B and C respectively ,since i wanted it to be SOA(Service Oriented Architecture) the way my setup works is when i send a request from client to server.

1. All the services are self hosted windows services.
2. Client sends request to **service A** (client has no clue about the other services B and C);
3. Service A eventually sends that request to Service B and Service C.
4. Service B and C sends response back to Service A which would be sent back to the client by service A.

**Issue i m facing** :If i make any changes in the code of Service B and rebuild and restart the service ,i am having issue getting the response back but when i restart all the remaining services then it works fine.

In other words my client doesn't get the response back unless i restart all the services(A,B and C) even though i just changed the code in only one service and rebuilt it.I know the thing works if i restart all the three services but i want to know is this the problem in my way of designing or it is something i have to deal with self hosted windows services.And all the services(A,B,C) are independent as none depends on each other.

Did some one ever see such things happened in SOA.I would be glad if some one can guide me to appropriate solution ?

Comment: If the version includes the build number and it is stored in generated proxies on the clients, that would explain why you have to refresh/rebuild the proxies.

Comment: You should log and research the issues you're claiming to have. Does an exception get thrown? What bindings do the services use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Replace WCF between services with any sort of queue (one service publishes something, other can read when they are ready). Can be anything. Can be a simple table where you read from if there is something new. Can be RabbitMQ, NServiceBus, etc, whatever works for you.
2. Define messages you put into the queue: commands and events. Both are simple classes with properties, no logic there. Commands represent what the system is asked to do (RegisterUser, PlaceOrder, ect), events represent what the system has done (UserRegistered, OrderApproved, PaymentReceived, etc). Be explicit about *actions*, Don't do something like "I have changed all the properties of a user on the client, now I call SaveUser(user)". *Your service* supposes to know *how* to change objects, clients should only command *what* to do.
3. Never break your contract. It is easy, easier than it sounds: you can *add* things to your message contracts, but cannot remove. In other word you just keep your contract backwards compatible.

Now you have a much better design: services communicate only through messages in queues, messages are backward compatible. This means that you can stop any of the services at any time without impacting others: they will continue sending messages into queues, and when the stopped service comes back again it will catch up processing all the stuff from the queue.

Then, if you want, you can use the same approach with client interactions: if instead of calling WCF clients would only put their *commands* in some sort of a queue then service upgrades or other downtime would not impact user experience.

Example: if I use WCF to place an order or to put an item into a shopping card then if there is a problem or a service is down for maintenance I will not be able to do it. I would click a button and have a nasty error. More importantly my order will not make into the system.
In contrast, if there is a queue in the middle, I only put my command into the queue. Now even if my service is down at the moment, or experience a high load (and therefore slow) then my user experience is still the same and does not degrade. It is just my command will be processed a bit later, but as a client I don't really care. And my order will not be lost in this scenario. The system became fault-tolerate and self-balanced.

There are all sorts of fantastic tricks you can do if you simply put a queue in the middle instead of experiencing problems with spatial and temporal coupling that comes with WCF :)
And what I described is just the beginning... :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a service bus such as [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com) to help you accomplish your functionality.

The first issue it will help you address is the decoupling of your services via publish/subscribe messaging pattern. Rather than invoking web services in one or the other service, publish events that notify the respective services when something has occurred. In your case this would look something like this:

1. Client invokes web service in Service A.
2. Service A publishes a message "Client Command Received" which Service B and C subscribe to.
3. Service B and C handle this event and then publish events of their own.
4. Service A subscribes to both events and replies to the client.

The first and immediate benefit of using something NServiceBus is reliability. On top of that you are able to easily version your message without affecting your client or your respective services. NServiceBus has full WCF integration so your client can continue to send messages to your service as before.

One of the things that makes your scenario interesting is that you can't guarantee when Service B and C send their responses back to you. Do you keep the connection to the client open until Service has received their responses? Do you need both responses before you can send a the client its response? What happens if either or one of the service crash? What if there is a time limit to how long you can wait before a response is received by Service A? All of these questions and more can be answered with a feature in NServiceBus called Sagas. Check it out.

If using NServiceBus is not possible then things become more difficult. WCF doesn't support publish/subscribe out of the box so you will have to bake your own. At a minimum I would recommend using this to decouple your services. How you manage state and temporal coupling in your services is another matter. Save yourself the trouble.

There are other frameworks out there but if you want a developer centric, cost effective way to create a .NET based solution then recommend using NServiceBus.